# Can a infinite ring have finite prime elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If the ring is $\mathbb{Z}$,we all know the answer is no because $p_1p_2...p_n+1$ is also a prime if we only have finite primes.I'm not sure if the idea also works in other rings.I think it's true if the ring is a UFD,and maybe we can consider some special situations such as a domain or a commutative ring.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99606/infinite-domain-with-finite-number-of-prime-idealselements.

Comment: Do you mean "finitely many"?  $\mathbb{Z}$ has finite primes e.g. $2$.  Pedantic - yes but this is mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring of $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$ is a local ring. Hence the only prime element is the element $p$. Clearly $\Bbb Z_p$ is an infinite ring.

Note that in $\Bbb Z$ it is *not* true, that
$p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ is again a prime - see [Prove or disprove $p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ is prime for all $ n\geq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121653/prove-or-disprove-p-1p-2-cdots-p-n1-is-prime-for-all-n-geq-1)

We have
$$
2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13+1=59\cdot 509.
$$

Comment: Thank you but you maybe misunderstand me.I mean that if we only have finite primes in $\mathbb{Z}$,then $p_1...p_n+1$ must be a prime so it contradicts.

Comment: @jdhejw Yes, I am sorry, you are right. I was thinking that we cannot have finitely many primes then, so that this need not be a prime.